# Unable to connect to Site to Site VPN on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, site-to-site-vpn

I am not able to connect to the computers on AWS using a Site to Site VPN.  I have set up the gateways on both sides and have configured the tunnels with the same parameters, but when I look at the tunnels on AWS, it shows that both tunnels are down.  I have tried setting up route tables and associating those route tables with my VPC, but I am not able to bring up the tunnel.  What am I missing?

Comment: If your tunnels are not up routes inside the VPC are irrelevant. Check your IP addresses (AWS and on-premises), passwords / shared secrets, that kind of thing. You can also turn on VPN logging when you create a new VPN, logs go into Cloudwatch Logs, you can try that to get logs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that all settings made according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html)
2. You can modify VPN connection options:

   2.1 Go to [VPC Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/) -> **Site-to-site VPN connections** -> Select your VPN connection -> **Actions** -> **Modify VPN connection options**

   2.2 Make them match:

   - Local IPv4 Network CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
   - Remote IPv4 Network CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0

   2.3 Reboot VPN on your machine
3. Check if you choose right vendor and made all according to downloaded configuration from **VPN connections** panel
4. If this is not working double check firewall rules that can block connection to your VPC
5. Double check your Customer and Virtual private gateway's settings. They must be made according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html)